# Updating PowerPoint slide element in presentation mode using Office API

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I would like to update text elements in a PPT slide-deck when the user starts the slideshow.

Q1: **Is there an event triggered when the slideshow starts?**

Q2: **How to I access a specific element (is there an id of sort)?**

Q3: **How to I change the text a specific element?**

Thank you

Comment: All three are possible in VBA but trapping events requires an installed add-in.  As to whether event trapping is possible in js ... I don't know, but am dubious.  More on the event as it appears to VBA:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.slideshowbegin